# Do we want to burninate the move tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the [move](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/move) is rather useless, do we want to destroy it? We need to reach a community consensus before Stack Exchange can do it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is more then useless since it does not specify anything palpable or that a user keeping it as a favorite will find it useful for tracking anything.

Comment: Je suis d'accord.

Comment: Très bien mon ami, je suis contente ;)

Comment: Well said.  I've asked a similar (but not duplicate) question regarding the new post tag here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14340/do-we-really-need-or-want-the-post-tag?noredirect=1#comment25124_14340